# Elasticsearch get users winning auctions (where users bid was highest) - something like having in SQL

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, having-clause, elasticsearch-nested

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.8.2. I'm trying to get all winning auctions by user_id=1. If I pass user_id=1 I want to get "Auction 1" because user_id=1 was the highest bidder.
I tried using Bucket Selector Aggregation but wasn't able to make it work because of the nested doc type.

Here is the schema and the sample data:

Schema:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "bids": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
{
    "title": "Auction 1",
    "price": 50,
    "bids": [
        {"user_id": 1, "amount": 100},
        {"user_id": 2, "amount": 200},
        {"user_id": 1, "amount": 300}
    ]
},{
    "title": "Auction 2",
    "price": 200,
    "bids": [
        {"user_id": 3, "amount": 300},
        {"user_id": 1, "amount": 400},
        {"user_id": 5, "amount": 500}
    ]
}
```

And the query I got so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "bids",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "bids.user_id": [
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "price": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me I'm desperate.